# Using CSS3 PIE for Gradient effect in IE8

Tags: html, css, css3pie

I am using [CSS3PIE](http://www.css3pie.com/) to generate gradient background for a div.

```
-pie-background: linear-gradient(#BFBBBB, #FFFFFF);
```

Above code renders the desired effect. But this fills the complete height of div with gradient.

I need to restrict the gradient upto few pixels (or percentage) from top of the div.

CSS3 equivalent for Chrome is

> background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom,
>   color-stop(0%, #BFBBBB), color-stop(30%, #FFFFFF));

The key here is `color-stop(30%, #FFFFFF)`. If you have used CSS3 PIE earlier, please suggest how to obtain `color-stop` property with CSS3-PIE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
linear-gradient(#BFBBBB, #FFFFFF 30%);
```

PIE uses the standard gradient syntax (with the exception of the direction parameter which has been changed in the spec but not yet updated within PIE.)

Speaking of which, you should also be using the standard syntax (prefixed where necessary) for other browsers as well. The old -webkit-gradient syntax is no longer the current preferred syntax.